# CSS Z index issue

Tags: html, css

I currently display the form with print details tool tip. I did atmost when i working in localhost (xampp) everything seems printing details tool tip aligned perfect, when i check in live that printing details tool tip is not showing properly.
I am not sure where i did the mistake.

Here is the Screenshot in localhost.
[image]

But in a live site [here](http://freenamecheck.com/demo/edd/?page_id=707)

is not working properly. Any suggestion would be great.

Thanks,
vicky

Comment: Can you post some code please, possible a jsfiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
#main-content .entry-content {
overflow: visible;  /* changed  */
padding: 20px 0;
}
```

it is better that you change `#print:hover+#tool_tip` to this:

```
#print:hover+#tool_tip, #tool_tip:hover {  /* <<<--- change is here  */
display: block;
background-color: #FF5C0A;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works great. why this should happen in live but not in localhost ?